# Aws::S3::Errors::BadDigest while trying to store a Tempfile

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, temporary-files, digest

I have the following snippet:

```
tempfile = Tempfile.new(export_file.filename)
begin
  tempfile.write(contents)
  file_storage_service.store(export_file.filename, tempfile)
ensure
  tempfile.close!
end
```

And the `store` method is as follows:

```
def store(filename, file)
  client = Aws::S3::Client.new(options)
  object = Aws::S3::Object.new(bucket_name, filename, client: client)
  object.upload_file(file)
end
```

My issue is that I seem to get a `Aws::S3::Errors::BadDigest` error on one of my cloud machines, but **locally** this works as expected.

I believe the tempfile is unlinked while the `store` method is being called, resulting in AWS comparing two different digests, but I'm not very sure about this. I have Ruby 2.1.6 on both machines, the local one running OS X and the cloud one Linux.

What can I do to fix this? And what's the cause of the problem?

P.S.: I've tried both `close!` and `close` on the tempfile, with the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that S3's `upload_file` expects a file with the cursor reset. Calling `tempfile.rewind` just before calling `store` solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok folks, my problem was even deeper. With `tempfile.rewind` the error disappeared but the changes made to the file directly were not reflected in memory, so instead of using rewind, I ended up using:

```
tempfile.close
tempfile.open
```

That fixed my problem completely !